# Private variable not available when component is mounted

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Example:

```
@Component
export default class MyVueComponent extends Vue {

    private _myVar: string = "not undefined";

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this._myVar);
    }

    mounted() {
        console.log(this._myVar);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
"not undefined"
undefined
```

---

I don't seem to find the keywords to google the problem properly. Intuitively it shouldn't behave like this, but it is evident that I am doing something wrong / not understanding a basic concept.

Comment: FYI that's not a truly `private` member, if you care.

Comment: What is the value of `this` inside `mounted`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, I know that the privacy of members are only enforced within the compiler.

Comment: @JamesMonger Good question: in `constructor`, `this = MyVueComponent` whereas in `mounted` `this = VueComponent`. Although I still don't quite understand what is going wrong and how can I solve it.

Comment: Changing `private _myVar` to `public _myVar` or even `_myVar` gives the same result: when `mounted` => `console.log(this._myVar); // undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The key to this one is how the `mounted` method is called.

## Constructor

If it is called as part of the `Vue` constructor, the variable can be undefined. Here's a demo with a cut down set up that sees `_myVar` is undefined...

```
class Vue {
    constructor() {
        this.mounted();
    }
}


class MyVueComponent extends Vue {

    private _myVar: string = "not undefined";

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this._myVar);
    }

    mounted() {
        console.log(this._myVar);
    }
}

const x = new MyVueComponent();
```

This is because of the ordering within your generated constructor, which looks like this:

```
function MyVueComponent() {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this; // <-- _myVar undefined
    _this._myVar = "not undefined"; // <-- and then it gets defined
    console.log(_this._myVar);
    return _this;
}
```

## Event / Scope Loss

The second possibility is if the method is called by an event, or in another case where the scope could be lost:

```
class Vue {
    constructor() {
    }
}


class MyVueComponent extends Vue {

    private _myVar: string = "not undefined";

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this._myVar);
    }

    mounted() {
        console.log(this._myVar);
    }
}

const x = new MyVueComponent();

// Scope Interrupted
window.setTimeout(x.mounted, 20);
```

In these cases, a scope-preserving arrow-function can solve the issue:

```
const x = new MyVueComponent();
window.setTimeout(() => x.mounted(), 20);
```

Comment: "because of the ordering within your generated constructor" => even if I delete the constructor, `_myVar` is still `undefined` when mounted. The constructor was just added as a way to be 100% sure that the `_myValue` was indeed not `undefined`, and it was before `mounted`.  As @JamesMonger made me realize in the comments:  in `constructor`, `this = MyVueComponent` whereas in `mounted` `this = VueComponent`. Also, `VueRouter` is taking care of the constructor, so I can't use an arrow-function (I think). I don't quite get it, and I feel like there is something more basic that I am doing wrong...